# Remover div "Pai"

Tags: jquery

Tenho o meu seguinte código:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            CONTEUDO 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            CONTEUDO 2
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            CONTEUDO 3
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

E quando eu clicar em "Delete" ele tem que deletar a div inteira (que contém a class "row") de seu respectivo conteúdo.

Como poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Rod, é você mesmo????

Comment: hã? como assim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode fazer assim

```js
$(function(){
    $('a.delete').click(function(){ 
        $(this).closest('.row').remove();
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            CONTEUDO 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary delete">Delete</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            CONTEUDO 2
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary delete">Delete</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            CONTEUDO 3
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary delete">Delete</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

A função `closest()` retorna o primeiro elemento que corresponde ao seletor especificado, começando a busca no elemento atual e subindo até encontrar.